# Kendo UI Mobile = data-template using dot notation for MVVM declarative bindings

Tags: javascript, templates, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have since deleted my prior posts regarding this.

Is there a way I can use dot notation to access Kendo UI templates through a widget's `data-template` attribute? I know the attribute currently accepts an ID to a script tag which contains the template, but I would like to overload/overwrite its functionality to accept a variable source.

The reason for this is because my templates are not wrapped in script tags, but are html files that get brought in to my app using the requireJS lib.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such way. Instead you have to specify the template [imperatively through pure JavaScript](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/templates.html).

Comment: thanks for your response. So, this would essentially require me to use imperative declaration for all widgets that use a custom template. Are there any plans to add support for this in the future?

Comment: No such plans, what you can try instead is to [extend](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/create-custom-kendo-widget) the widget you need. This you can add extra options which inside your init implementation can override the template the way you need it.

Comment: Could you help to show an example where the data-template can be overwritten/set within the extended widget's init? I have followed the documentation link but I was not able to override the template. My goal was to set data-template="app.template.nav". Then in the init I would use bracket notation to acquire and load in my template.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for would be relatively easy if `kendo.initWidget` would use `kendo.parseOptions` instead of a private reference to that function. You could still make those changes, but as it is, it may be easier to use a custom widget, as suggested by Petur.

**Example**

Your app object containing the template:

```
window.app = {
    template: {
        autoComplete: "this row: #= data #"
    }
}
```

The widget definition:

```
var autoCompleteWidget = (function (init) {
    return kendo.ui.AutoComplete.extend({
        options: {
            name: 'AutoComplete'
        },
        init: function (element, options) {
            var templateLocation = $(element).data("template-location");
            if (templateLocation) {
                options.template = (0, eval)(templateLocation);
            }
            init.call(this, element, options);
        }
    });

})(kendo.ui.AutoComplete.fn.init);
kendo.ui.plugin(autoCompleteWidget);
```

HTML (you could simply use data-template, but using a different attribute may be a useful reminder this is using a different approach and doesn't accept DOM ids):

```
<input data-role="autocomplete" 
 data-template-location="app.template.autoComplete" data-bind="source: data" />
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/vwwkn/))